# Clase que lea fechas y compruebe si el día es correcto

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, date

Buenas tardes.

Estoy tratando de hacer una clase que obtenga datos concretos (día, mes y año) para luego tratarlo en otra.

Quiero hacer una comprobación en la propia clase y es comprobar que si es correcto el día respecto al mes, es decir, si es Febrero, evidentemente Dia no puede ser 30.

Adjunto código que llevo por el momento. He visto otra pregunta similar en el foro JAVA y es mas o menos lo que quiero hacer, pero no se como lo puedo llevar a cabo en C#.

```
class cLeer
{
    private int nAnyo;
    private int nMes;
    private int nDia;
    public cLeer()
    {
        nAnyo = 0;
        nMes = 0;
        nDia = 0;
    }

    public int Anyo
    {
        get { return nAnyo; }
        set
        {
            if(value>=1900 && value <= 2199)
            {
                value = nAnyo;
            }
        }
    }

    public int Mes
    {
        get { return nMes; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 12)
            {
                value = nMes;
            }
        }
    }
    public int Dia
    {
        get { return nDia; }
        set
        {
            ... ...
        }
    }
}
```

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Mira en https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx debes considerar el formato que acepta como fecha válida.

Comment: Puedes comprobarlo directamente con `new DateTime(nAnyo, nMes, nDia)` y ver si te arroja un error, ¿por qué necesitas reinventar la rueda?

Comment: ¿Es un ejercicio de programación para alguna clase?

Comment: Si, es un ejercicio de programación (vamos, que estoy estudiando un módulo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- En el constructor sin parámetros no es necesario inicializar los valores en 0 ya que el declararlos , **`el valor por defecto para los Int asignado es 0`**
- El `Set` de los atributos de la clase, realizas mal la asignación  `value = nMes;`, tienes que asignar el valor que ingresa al atributo más no al contrario. `nMes = value;`
- Para realizar la comprobación de los días puedes usar el método [DaysInMonth(año ,mes )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) de [Datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime) , donde los parámetros que recibe es el año y el mes y el valor de retorno es la cantidad de días del mes y año pasado por parámetro , Tener en cuenta que si los valores de mes o año son inválidos, lanzará una `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

  ```
  public int Dia
  {
      get { return nDia; }
      set
      {
         /* Comprobamos que el valor retornado de la función sea mayor al día ingresado , 
            además que sea  mayor o igual a 1 */
          if (DateTime.DaysInMonth(nAnyo, nMes) >= value && value >= 1) nDia = value;
          else Console.WriteLine("Día Ingresado es Incorrecto");
      }
  }
  ```

  Otra posible solución sería validar en el constructor con parámetros que por cierto te falta añadir:

  ```
  public cLeer(int dia, int mes, int anio)
   {
      if (anio >= 1900 || anio <= 2199) nAnyo = anio;
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Año Ingresado es Incorrecto");
          nAnyo = 2000; /* Un año por Defecto */
      }
      if (mes > 0 || mes <= 12) nMes = mes;
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Mes Ingresado es Incorrecto");
          nMes = 1; /* Un Mes por Defecto */
      }
      if (DateTime.DaysInMonth(nAnyo, nMes) >= dia && dia >= 1) nDia = dia;
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Día Ingresado es Incorrecto");
          nDia = 1; /* Un Día por Defecto */
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Estaba buscando algo así, no sabía que se podia validar en el propio constructor. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el Tryparse de .Net
Le envia la fecha en un formato especifico y si la conversión fue exitosa, es porque el día, mes y año son una fecha valida.

[Documentación y ejemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: De la referencia que indicas, podrías [editar tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/63979/edit) e incluir parte del código para una mejor comprensión.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario [reinventar la rueda](http://losvericuetosdotnet.blogspot.mx/2014/11/la-importancia-de-no-reinventar-la.html) (recuérdalo bien), puedes hacer una simple validación:

```
class cLeer
{
    public static DateTime Fecha(int Anyo, int Mes, int Dia)
    {
        try
        {
            return new DateTime(Anyo, Mes, Dia);
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            // Aquí decides qué hacer en caso de que no sea una fecha válida.
            // Algunas opciones son:
            return null;
            //
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("La fecha no es válida.");
            //
            throw;
            //
            return DateTime.Now;
            //
            return new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
            //
            return new DateTime(); // Con el dato por default.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me gustaría comentarte que utilizar un try/catch para gestionar el flujo de programa esta totalmente desaconsejado. Puedes echar un vistazo a [esta pregunta (en ingles)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336094/is-it-bad-to-use-try-catch-for-flow-control-in-net) y a numerosos articulos que hablan sobre el tema. Un saludo

Comment: Claro, lo mejor es que si ocurre una excepción se informe al usuario y el flujo se detenga, pero ese no es el punto de la pregunta, por eso aclaro que, en caso de usar un `try-catch` tiene que decidir qué va a aplicar ¡Saludos y buen día!